# How do I restore icons in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, dock, crash, icon

So yesterday I tried opening one of my apps an the Dock just froze completely. I tried every tip I could find online like Command+Option+Escape and `killall -KILL Dock`, but nothing fixed it. I was finally forced to restart my MacBook Pro. Now, my Finder looks like this:

[image: Finder with no icons]

How do I fix Finder?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can reset OS X's icon cache with the following commands. Just copy and paste each into a Terminal window and then reboot your Mac.

```
 sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
 sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
 sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
```

Source: [Clearing the Icon Services cache in Yosemite](http://furbo.org/2015/01/19/clearing-the-icon-services-cache-in-yosemite/)

Comment: Seems that the first two don't work in High Sierra.

Comment: Still works in High Sierra. Not sure how one would verify whether the first two commands work or not without running just those and rebooting, but the instructions said to run all 3, and after running those and rebooting, icons returned.

Comment: In spite of the fact that in High Sierra (10.13.6) the commands returned about a dozen "Operation not permitted" warnings, when I rebooted, the icons were restored.

Answer (score 0):

For high sierra, restarting in safe mode did the trick for me.

Choose Apple menu > Shut Down.

After your Mac shuts down, wait 10 seconds, then press the power button.

Immediately after your Mac starts (some Mac computers play a startup sound), press and hold the Shift key.

Release the Shift key when you see the gray Apple logo and progress indicator.

To leave safe mode, restart your Mac again, but don’t press and hold any keys during startup.

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25617?locale=en_US